# Point to point to point wireless LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

Is it possible to use point to point wireless technology in repetitive succession to create a linear network that spans a great distance?

The network:

Would consist of 2-20 nodes.
Each node will have line of sight to the next and previous node.
Each node adds one device.
The first node should control all others.
All nodes need only communicate with node #1.
Will be dismantled and rebuilt every few weeks.
Node distances from each other are between 50'-1000'.
Distance from first to last node should reach 1 mile or more.
Distances will change with every installation.
Number of nodes will change with every installation.

My research suggests that this is possible, but I'd like to get a few second opinions. Any thoughts?

**update**

The network would also have each node/device use up to 10Mbps bandwidth.

After further research I'm certain this is possible. I've looked into WirelessHART and Ubiquity products, both have similar system features, but neither suited my needs.

A mixed mesh network using P2P wireless turns out to be a little more common than I expected; I'm seeing many similar applications but none that I can use "out of the box".

I think I can narrow my question a bit:

1:To what extent can I mix wireless and wired technologies?

For example:1x router, 3x access points, and 8x Point to point, possibly alternating between wireless to wired to p2p to wireless, etc.

2: When mixing devices, do brands matter? Possible compatibility issues?

3: Which spectrum is better suited for this application, 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz?

4: Any personal experience out there with wireless bridging?

Comment: I'm not sure if you ever heard of [WirelessHART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WirelessHART) technology but it may suffice or be something worth reading up on a bit more to determine for sure. I assume you aren't trying to develop your own new protocol for such a topology and environment but maybe that'll help give you a starting point at least.

Comment: [Ubiquiti](https://www.ubnt.com/airfiber/airfiber24-hd/) has hard and software designed for purposes like yours, but on a bigger scale. Look if you like the technology behind this and search for similar but 'weaker' hardware. For your setup you really don't need a node with a reach of 100km.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Engenious ENH500AC directional antennas in a wireless bridge format for a prototype, using three nodes in a star topology. The small scale project was a success, and I intend to expand on this and create a spanning tree system soon. The equipment is a bit overkill, but successful nonetheless. All research and field testing suggests that my aforementioned system should work without a hitch. Thanks to those that responded, and I hope that this thread helps someone with their project.